# Getting list of messages from Twilio with pagenation

Tags: node.js, twilio, twilio-api

I want to get all the messages from my twilio account.

I tried this code

```
var client = new twilio(twilioConfig.accountSid, twilioConfig.authToken);

client.messages.list({ Page: 0, PageSize: 10 }, function (err, data) {
    console.log(data);
        res.send({ message: "Success" });
});
```

in this code getting all messages, i need 10 per page

Comment: Which version of the Twilio package are you using?

Comment: Does it need to be `pageSize` instead of `PageSize`?

Comment: Also, what is the actual problem you are facing? Are you trying to get all the messages? Or are you trying to just get 10 messages?

Comment: i want all messages, with 10 per page @philnash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

If you are using the latest version of the [Twilio Node module](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/node) then you can get all your messages in a couple of ways.

You can call [`each` on the message list object](https://twilio.github.io/twilio-node/3.5.0/Twilio.Api.V2010.AccountContext.MessageList.html#each) which lazily streams the messages.

```
const client = require('twilio')(YOUR_ACCOUNT_SID, YOUR_AUTH_TOKEN);

client.messages.each({ pageSize: 10 }, function(message) {
  console.log(message);
});
```

Or you can call [`list` on the message list](https://twilio.github.io/twilio-node/3.5.0/Twilio.Api.V2010.AccountContext.MessageList.html#list), which eagerly loads all of the messages.

```
client.messages.list({ pageSize: 10 }, function(messages) {
  messages.forEach(function(message) {
    console.log(message);
  });
});
```

You can also use [`page`](https://twilio.github.io/twilio-node/3.5.0/Twilio.Api.V2010.AccountContext.MessageList.html#page) and subsequently `nextPage` to manually page through all of the messages.

```
client.messages.page({ pageSize: 10 }, function pageReceived(page) {
  page.instances.forEach(function(message) {
    console.log(message);
  });
  if (page.nextPage) {
    page.nextPage().then(pageReceived);
  }
})
```

Let me know if any of that helps at all.

Comment: client.messages.page is working fine, but how to call next page

Comment: The page object you get in the callback should have a `nextPage()` method that uses the [paging information returned in the response](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/response#response-formats-list-paging-information) to fetch the next set of messages.